# Referencing the physical resource ID in a AwsCustomResource in onUpdate or onDelete

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to create an `AwsCustomResource` to make [single AWS API calls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/custom-resources-readme.html#custom-resources-for-aws-apis), specifically `(create|update|delete)-organisational-unit`. In the `onCreate` I can see that to return the OU's Id as the physical resource ID I can specify a `physicalResourceIdPath`, however for the `onUpdate` and `onDelete` I need to specify this in the API call.

I can not see how, other than to use regular custom resources with my own Lambda to gain access to the `event`.

Here is what I have so far, `'help?'` is what I'm missing.

```js
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { AwsCustomResource } from '@aws-cdk/custom-resources'

export interface OrganisationalUnitProps {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly parentId: string;
}

export class OrgansationalUnit extends AwsCustomResource {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: OrganisationalUnitProps) {
    super(scope, id, {
      onCreate: {
        service: 'Organizations',
        action: 'createOrganizationalUnit',
        parameters: {
          Name: props.name,
          ParentId: props.parentId
        },
        physicalResourceIdPath: 'OrganizationalUnit.Id'
      },
      onDelete: {
        service: 'Organizations',
        action: 'deleteOrganizationalUnit',
        parameters: {
          OrganizationalUnitId: 'help?'
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: In the meantime I've gone back to just using a regular custom resource in CDK, although since I need to do this for multiple sets of 'single AWS API calls' much of my code is duplicated. I may look at tsconfig/some bundler to extract the common code and make my own version of the Lambda that `AwsCustomResource` uses. Another feature request I'd have of it is that it retries when the API response indicates it's failed but retryable. It would be nice for this to be included OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst there isn't a perfectly clean way to do it yet, here is an answer I was given in this [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6985) that I raised on the CDK github page.

You create two custom resources. One is just a create, and one is just a delete.

```js
const connectDirectory = new AwsCustomResource(this, 'ConnectDirectory', {
  onCreate: {
    service: 'DirectoryService',
    action: 'connectDirectory',
    parameters: { ... },
    physicalResourceId: PhysicalResourceId.fromResponse('DirectoryId')
  },
});
const deleteDirectory = new AwsCustomResource(this, 'DeleteDirectory', {
  onDelete: {
    service: 'DirectoryService',
    action: 'deleteDirectory',
    parameters: {
      DirectoryId: connectDirectory.getResponseField('DirectoryId'),
    },
  },
});
```

That github issue has been accepted as a change request, so there may be a better answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

nowadays there is [PhysicalResourceIdReference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_custom-resources.PhysicalResourceId.html) which you can use like this:

```js
new AwsCustomResource(this, 'my-custom-resource', {
    ...
    onCreate: {
        ...
        physicalResourceId: PhysicalResourceId.fromResponse( ... )
    },
    onDelete: {
        ...
        parameters: {
            physicalResourceId: new PhysicalResourceIdReference(),      
        }
    }
});
```